# Adding a Bot to Azure Communication Service Chat Thread using the Microsoft App Id failed

Tags: c#, azure-bot-service, azure-communication-services

I would like to add a Chat Bot using a [Bot Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/abs-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned) as a participant to our existing [Azure Communication Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/create-communication-resource?tabs=windows&pivots=platform-azp) Chat Thread.

Following the instruction given by Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/chat/quickstart-botframework-integration#start-a-chat-thread-with-the-bot), the code to do that is:

```
var chatParticipant = new ChatParticipant(identifier: new CommunicationUserIdentifier(id: "<BOT_ID>"))
{
    DisplayName = "BotDisplayName"
};
CreateChatThreadResult createChatThreadResult = await chatClient.CreateChatThreadAsync(topic: "Hello Bot!", participants: new[] { chatParticipant });
ChatThreadClient chatThreadClient = chatClient.GetChatThreadClient(threadId: createChatThreadResult.ChatThread.Id);
string threadId = chatThreadClient.Id;
```

To get the Bot ID, I need to go Configuration and take the Microsoft App ID:
[image]

The format is like: *2647dbd1-f3b9-4f55-9990-5b09d5XXXXXX*

But when I take a look on our existing Azure Communication Service User Ids it's more like:
*8:acs:bdba939d-38ab-4c4f-8415-bb97a4f1d291_0000001d-09bf-5a56-2633-8e3a0dXXXXXX*

At first look, this is strange, but maybe it could work ...

But when I try, I always have the same issue:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Where is my mistake? How to be able to add the bot as a participant?